# Matlab: how do you lock the secondary y-axis when zooming in or out of a plot?

Tags: matlab

How do you lock the secondary y-axis when zooming in or out of a plot? I am using plotyy (Matlab R2010a) and would like to zoom, both vertically and horizontally, data plotted against the primary y-axis but have the secondary y-axis be vertically static.

Comment: What is the secondary y-axis? Could you give simple example code that creates such a graph?

Comment: x = [0:10]; y1 = x*3; y2 = x.^3; plotyy(x,y1,x,y2); The secondary y-axis would be the y-axis on the right-hand side of the plot.